# How to make a progressbar with a icon?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I know how to set the width of the progressBar by renderer it in ios/android.But is there anyway to add a image in the progressbar?

I have set its height.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.ScaleY = 20;
        }
```

and in ios:

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();

            var x = 1.0f;
            var y = 20.0f;

            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(x, y);
            Control.Transform = transform;
        }
```

but I wonder if there is anyway to add an icon?
this is my goal to achive:
[progressBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kALa9.png)
it is a 98 percent progressBar with a star in the end of the progress value.I've no idea to achive it

Comment: You could hack together a solution using a grid or absolute layout. That means no need for custom renderers and you’ll have a consistent view between platforms.

Comment: @Skin Thank you .I know that way of grid But it is not a better way is it? I want to find the best way .

Comment: well, define “best way” ...! If you use some smarts in forms only than you negate the need for a renderer that’s required on all platforms. Getting a result in forms would be pretty straight forward. Find the width of the progress bar, it’s current value in a percentage and then translateX the star by that amount. Tie that to the progress bar change code you write and you should be good. It’s only my opinion. If that’s not your cup of tea then here’s hoping someone answers your question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's too late to reply now

Have you try to use `Slider` and use CustomRender to custom the style of `SeekBar`,it has the
`android:thumb="@drawable/seekbarthumb"` attribute,set your star icon to the `thumb` more easily

Answer (score 0):

at last I use relativelayout to fix the postion of the image. as @Skin says.